# How do I create a post / page without needing get_header() and get_footer()?

Tags: themes

So basically the title. My theme is Elementor.

I created a page template and without the header and footer the styling is completely messed up. How can I make it so I don't need the header and footer?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace `get_header()`, copy the code from theme's `header.php` into your page template, and to replace `get_footer()`, copy the code from theme's `footer.php` into your page template.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So I did what was mentioned and header.php contained HTML code, so it didn't format correctly and the styling remained the same.

Comment: Make sure you copy and paste correctly, for instance, HTML code should not go inside of PHP tags.

Comment: The HTML code wasn't inside the tags and the formatting remained the same. It seems like it might be a thing where it requires the functions get_header()

Comment: The main functions you need to check are present are `wp_head()` in between the `<head>` tags, and `wp_footer()` before the closing `<body>` tag.

Comment: Ahhh I looked at the wrong header.php and footer.php file. Works like a charm! Thank you very much